# lighttpd, redirect just the IP to https and a specific port?

Tags: lighttpd

My lighttpd.conf file currently...

```
server.port = 8000
...
$SERVER["socket"] == ":8080" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "([^:/]+)" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1:8000/$1" )
    }
}

server.modules = (
   "mod_accesslog",
   "mod_fastcgi",
   "mod_rewrite",
   "mod_auth",
   "mod_redirect"
)
...
```

Right now I can get all traffic heading to port 8080 to redirect to port 8000 (where everything is actually located). I want to be able to type in the IP itself (working with IP's here) and it redirects you to https and port 8000 (e.g. `101.102.103.104 => https://101.102.103.104:8000`). Right now I can get `101.102.103.104:8080 => https://101.102.103.104:8000`. I want to use just the IP.

---

Solved.

The default port is 80. So use the following:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1:8000/$1" )
    }
}
```

This redirects everything that comes in on port 80 (10.10.10.10 would default to port 80) to port 8000 with https.

Answer (score 0):

So, is this solved or not?

By specifying `101.102.103.104` your browser defaults to port `80`. So, if lighttpd is listening on port `80`, you can capture/redirect using the same technique you described.

In the configuration [documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_Configuration) it says that the daemon will bind to ports specified in `$SERVER["socket"] ==` conditionals. 
e.g.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "([^:/]+)" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1:8000/$1" )
    }
}
```

The above config should guarantee lighttpd will have bound to port `80` and will also make redirects to port `8000`.